# Give listview items tags without custom arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've got a question that should be simple, but I can't seem to solve it.

I'm using [DragSortListView](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview). I want to give each listview-item a tag with it's original location. When the user is done reordering I want to return a string with original id's (such as 2,3,4,1 if the user moved the first item to the last place). If a item is deleted, I also would like to know the orignal ID.

Here is my code.

```
DragSortListView mainListView = (DragSortListView) findViewById( R.id.list_pages );  
String[] names = settings.getString("pages", "Error,error").split(",");    
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, list);
mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);
DragSortController controller = new DragSortController(mainListView);
...
```

Now I thought it would be best to loop through all items and give them tags with their original id's. I'm trying to loop through the items using something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < mainListView.getCount(); i++)
{
  View v = mainListView.getChildAt(i);
  TextView tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
  tx.setTag(i);
}
```

However this listview appears to be empty, even though the adapter has been set.

I can't use a custom ArrayAdapter, as the app will crash when an item is dropped or swiped away.

**Additional info:**
The listview is populated when data is returned by a service using a BroadcastReceiver. I don't think this influences this, but you never know.

My question:

- How do I store each list-items original position, so that I can access it later on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use a custom `Adapter`, then you can just do it like this:

```
    List<Item> dataForTheAdapter = new ArrayList<Item>();

    // 'dataRetrivedfromService' is the data, that gets returned by the service
    for (int counter = 0; counter < dataRetrivedfromService.size(); counter++) {
        dataForTheAdapter.add(new Item(dataRetrivedfromService.get(counter), counter));
    }

    mContext = MyActivity.this;
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(mContext, R.layout.row, dataForTheAdapter);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

This code is pretty self explanatory. Now looking at the Item.java class, you'll see that I overrode the `toString()` method. The `toString()` method get's called on the supplied object the ListView want's to fill up its data with.

```
public class Item {

    private String mText;
    private int mPosition;

    public Item(String text, int position) {

        this.mText = text;
        this.mPosition = position;
    }

    public int getPosition() {

        return mPosition;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {

        this.mPosition = position;
    }

    public String getText() {

        return mText;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {

        this.mText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return this.mText;
    }
}
```

Now you won't have to write a custom Adapter, but can fill up your ListView with an Item's object.

To test this if it works, you can set an `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` and do this:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(mAdapter.getItem(position).getPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Really helpful answer, thanks Ahmad! Since this is a different adapter  it still changed my `setDropListener()` and `setRemoveListener()`, but I'll figure that out. As soon as I do, I will mark this as complete :) Thanks again!

Comment: Done! This answer was perfect. Thanks!